# Joomla problem: where does "$mainframe->getCfg('lang')" come from?

Tags: joomla, config

In Joomla:

```
$mainframe->getCfg('lang');
```

will return "english" (i think this is a default value), anyone can tell me where defined it?

Can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

It's what you configure in the Language Manager.

Answer (score 1):

jlleblanc,thanks for your help.
i think i find the problem: its language files' problem,just change the `backwardLang` in `metadata`,Here are the codes:

```
<metadata>
<name>Simplified Chinese</name>
<tag>zh-CN</tag>
<rtl>0</rtl>
<locale>zh_CN.utf8, zh, zho, zhi, zh_CN, zho_CN, zhi_CN, simplified_chinese</locale>
<winCodePage>cp936</winCodePage>
<backwardLang>simplified_chinese</backwardLang>
</metadata>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla! 1.5, go to Extensions > Language Manager. This will list all of the languages currently installed on your system, including the default (which you can set).

However, users can also select the language they want to use. The code $mainframe->getCfg('lang'); will return the language selected by the user instead of the default.

Also, you should avoid using the $mainframe object and instead retrieve the current language using JFactory:

```
$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
echo $lang->getName();
```